# Is there a way to generate a clang-format file from a C++ code?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, clang-format

Supposing I have a C++ code already written and I want to generate a clang-format file from it, in order to note all the format settings of my code in this file, is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Can try https://github.com/johnmcfarlane/unformat but doesn't work that reliably

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Clang-Format Detector](https://www.clangpowertools.com/blog/getting-started-with-clang-format-detector.html#:%7E:text=The%20Clang-Format%20Detector%20can%20be%20accessed%20in%20two%20ways%3A&text=From%20Visual%20Studio%20by%20going,Format%20tab%20%3E%20Clang-Format%20Editor&text=From%20the%20standalone%20Clang-Format%20Editor) allows to generate clang-format file for the selected files. It also has a very convenient feature of seeing the result and adjusting it. Won't work for entire codebase though.